# Is the Google Books API connected to Google Play store?

Tags: google-api, google-play

I'm using [Google Books API](https://developers.google.com/books/docs/v1/using#PerformingSearch), to check if a book is in the Google Play Store.

Now I'm wondering my assumption is correct:

> If the API returns title with a property value for_sale, this book
>   title is automatically available in Google Play Store.

Due to the fact that using this url:

https://www.googleapis.com/books/v1/volumes?q=isbn%3D$9789460420726&maxResults=1&printType=books&showPreorders=true

tells me that totalitems = 0.

But when I search for the book in Google Play store, I can see that the book is available:
https://play.google.com/store/books/details/Freddy_Willockx_Hier_klopt_mijn_hart?id=_rkZBAAAQBAJ

A URL with a book that has the correct information:
https://www.googleapis.com/books/v1/volumes?q=isbn%3D$9789044976830&maxResults=1&printType=books&showPreorders=true

https://play.google.com/store/search?q=9789044976830

Hope someone can help me out.

Answer (score 0):

My guess (and it is just a guess) would be a location issue. Following [the link you gave](https://play.google.com/store/books/details/Freddy_Willockx_Hier_klopt_mijn_hart?id=_rkZBAAAQBAJ) shows me the book, but I cannot purchase it (I am in the UK).

It is possible the API returns for_sale for books that are for sale in the US, or for sale in all locales, or some other definition. Or maybe your API call is not being identified as coming from the correct country.